# Question about TCP/IP socket data transportation time

Tags: networking, sockets

I have a problem that I have to test a TCP/IP connection beetween two computers. My setup is two computers without a DHCP router, both computers are Ubuntu 16.04 and I use a 128 kb message as a test. I send a message from computer A  to computer B and than pass it back. That single pass takes about 30 to 60 ms. My question is is this normal? Also I would appreciate if someone could test and verify this. My problem is that I need that time to to drop to around 10 ms. Is that possible?

Comment: You can use `iperf` to measure network speeds at higher volumes.

Comment: Additionally, with iperf or iperf3 we can tell you our results for the same test. I'm not sure how to do the test you are describing.

Comment: The result would give me a hint but this iperf tool I will take a coler look and see how it works